# How to create responsive designs for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I'm a serious beginner, trying to work my way through a variety of design challenges in HTML and CSS (and eventually JS.) I consistently find myself running into the same theme of problems in each of the projects I work on: I'm often confused as to how I should make good responsive design choices.

As examples, I'm often confused as to which units I should use (whether it be pixels, or percentages, or em, or whatever other kinds of units), I'm confused as to whether it would be best to use media queries or if I should use bootstrap, I'm confused about whether I should use any kind of tool above any other kind of tool to make my site more responsive.

To clarify, my question isn't really about how to use any of these particular tools. It's about general principles that will guide my thinking when making design choices for responsive sites and choosing the right tools for the project. Does anyone know of any good guides that help me make good and responsive designs?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS flexbox and grid layout modes are worth taking the time to learn first.

Check out these two articles from CSS Tricks:

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

They are powerful on their own and naturally lead to a responsive design when used properly.

Bootstrap and other frameworks are using these under the hood in different places, so knowing them will help regardless if you end up writing your own or using something like Bootstrap.